# Passing a constant value to a function

Tags: c, pointers, floating-point, constants, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass a float32_t * const value to a function argument and I am getting exception errors. I have tried a lot of things but still receiving errors. My function is:

```
float32_t Distance(float32_t *const argDistance);
```

where **float32_t** is: `typedef float float32_t;`

I am trying to access this function like this:

```
float32_t* const tempTipDistance = 0;
```

but it tends to throw an exception:

```
SEH exception with code 0xc0000005 thrown in the test body.
```

Any suggestions on how to pass a value to this function?

Comment: So, where is the Distance function implementation and call?

Comment: `C0000005` is Windows' way of saying segfault, which, in your case, is caused by dereferencing the null pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are sending in a pointer containing a `0` memory address, which is an invalid address to access. If you want to send in a pointer to the value `0.0` use:

```
float32_t value = 0.0;
float32_t* const tempTipDistance = &value;
```

Comment: I swear I tried this a couple of minutes ago and it din't work and suddenly it started working.